# How to solve HTTP Error 500.0 - Internal Server Error on IIS10?

Tags: .net, xml, internal-server-error, iis-10, http-status-code-500

I've been playing with this for a while now, but I haven't found any similar issue online. I'm using Windows 10 Home 1909 and IIS-10. This is the structure of my application:

***DIRECTORY:***

`"C:\inetpub\wwwroot\website1"` - (contains files: `iisstart.htm`, `iisstart.png`, `index.html`, `index.php`, `web.config`)

---

***web.config:***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <directoryBrowse enabled="true" />

<!--I have also tried with and without these
            <requestFiltering>
                <hiddenSegments>
                    <remove segment="App_GlobalResources" />
                    <remove segment="App_code" />
                    <remove segment="bin" />
                    <remove segment="App_Browsers" />
                    <remove segment="App_Data" />
                    <remove segment="App_WebReferences" />
                    <remove segment="App_LocalResources" />
                </hiddenSegments>
            </requestFiltering>
-->
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

*`"website1.com/index.html"` - works fine*

***`"website1.com"`*** and **`"website1.com/index.php"`** will give the following error:

### [image: Demo 1]

***IIS10 (CONNECTION website1.com):***

- DEFAULT DOCUMENTS: `index.php`, `Default.htm`, `Default.asp`, `index.htm`, `index.html`, `iisstart.html`, `default.aspx` with entry type INHERITED (please note that under DEKSTOP-... the same files exists but the entry type is "LOCAL")
- PERMISSION (IIS_IUSRS): has all permissions to dir:`"C:\xampp\php_7_2_31"`
- FastCgiModule was installed using these tutorials: [link1](https://vlemon.com/blog/php7/how-to-install-php-in-iis-windows-10/), [link2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/cgi#:~:text=In%20Control%20Panel%2C%20click%20Programs,Click%20OK.) step by step.
- APPLICATION POOLS:

### [image: Demo 2]

***CMD: (Microsoft Visual C++ 2015 Redistibutable (x64) - 14.0.23026 is installed)***

[image: Demo 3]

---

***Windows Features:***

[image: Demo 4]

---

Now is the fun part (I have no idea how to proceed).

Looks like that .NET is not triggered therefore FastCGI gives the error. I tried adding the following in the Windows Features:

a)  `.NET Extensibility 3.5` & `ASP NET 3.5` - restarted my machine and tried it out and it changes the HTTP ERROR to 500.24

b) `.NET Extensibility 4.8` & `ASP NET 4.8` - restarted my machine and tried it out and it changes the HTTP ERROR to 500.24

c) `.NET Extensibility 3.5` & `ASP NET 3.5` & `.NET Extensibility 4.8` & `ASP NET 4.8` - restarted my machine and tried it out and it changes the HTTP ERROR to 500.24

Please if you know how to solve this, do let me know. I have tried all tutorials, forums and couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there is any space between your php.exe file folder path? if there is space between php_7_2_31 then remove it first.

Look like iis can not read the configuration of PHP from the camp folder. to resolve the issue just try to install PHP from the web platform installer. it is easy to download and use. you no need to do extra configuration in iis after installing it.

https://www.microsoft.com/web/downloads/platform.aspx

Comment: I have download the version of PHP i wanted (7.2.26), through `Web Platform Installer` and was all normal, except that it didn't install `PHP Manager for IIS`. So I have downloaded that separately though the `Web Platform Installer`. Also, I have changed the pool of the application to `Classic .NET AppPool`.

Everything looks okay and the index.php file now works. Thanks a lot :D